# Perform two bitwise operations on a column in one MySQLi query?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, bitwise-operators

**Is it possible to perform two bitwise operations to a single column in MySQLi in the same query?**

I have a column called status, and this column holds various different flags, from 1 to 64 (at the moment, this may grow). In one query I would like to clear the first flag, which I know is set, and then set the last flag, whose status I don't know. I know the operations I need to perform, an `XOR` on the first one, and an `OR` on the last one, but can I do both in one query?

At first I thought I could use a `CASE` like this example below:

```
UPDATE products 
SET pStatus = CASE pId 
    WHEN 66 THEN pStatus ^ 1 
    WHEN 66 THEN pStatus | 64 
END 
WHERE pId IN (66);
```

However that just runs the first `XOR`, but not the second `OR`.

I also thought you might be able to just run both functions one after the other, like this:

```
UPDATE products 
SET pStatus ^ 1 | 64 
WHERE pId = 66
```

However that just produces a syntax error.

***Does anyone have a solution where I can run both in one query?***

---

**EDIT AND SOLUTION**

I was close with my query above, combining them together. Thanks to @SylvainLeroux for putting me on to the correct syntax with his answer below. The correct working statement is:

```
UPDATE products 
SET pStatus = (pStatus ^ 1) | 64 
WHERE pId = 66
```

Comment: Please indent your query so it's (more) clear where you do the grouping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitwise operators (`^`, `|`, `&`) are *plain* operators. You can combine them. Have you tried that:

```
UPDATE products 
SET pStatus = (pStatus ^ 1) | 64 
WHERE pId = 66;
```

Comment: I hadn't tried with the brackets, no, but that still produces a syntax error.

Comment: Ignore my last comment, I hadn't done `pStatus =` either >.<. Thank you, that worked :).